# wamp webserver access the root directory

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp, localhost, wamp

I was using xampp 2.4  webserver on my windows vista. I installed wamp 2.0 recently 
**the problem is** : when I type http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 I get the root directory for xampp not for the wamp 
**any idea about how to reach the wamp root folder from the browser ??** 
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess xampp is probably running on port 80 which is the default.

You need to edit your Apache config for WAMP and set the port to something like 8080

This link might help:

http://www.ehow.com/how_5178964_change-number-apache-server-wamp.html

Oh and make sure you also start WAMP.